Running single containers on a cluster/set of docker servers
I'm looking for a solution to run many more or less short-lived single containers (not services / stacks) distributed over several docker servers. There is no need for high-availability / replication or anything like this for each container itself, but I want one single address to connect to with the docker client, and I then want the container scheduled on any connected docker server (that has available resources).
The use case is: running containers that are dependencies for builds, scheduled by Testcontainers (or the Jenkins docker agent plugin). This poses the constraint that these tools start the containers with docker run (or the API equivalent), and don't support abstractions like services or stacks or the like.
I naively assumed that would be possible with docker swarm mode. But that uses service or stack abstractions to run distributed apps. Single containers with docker run seem to always run on the node that is defined in DOCKER_HOST on the client, and not distributed among the worker nodes.
Is there any way to achieve that with docker swarm mode that I overlokked, or is there any other product / tool that does that?

One possible solution is to use/implement Kubernetes where you can define the number of specific container instances.

This is in no way a solution. I stated clearly: I don't need multiple instances of the same container, I only care about running a bunch of independent containers. I also clearly stated that my hard, externally driven requirement is to run containers with the Docker API, and that I'm not able to use abstractions like service, stack (Docker Swarm) or by conclusion Pods or Deployments (Kunernetes).
